# Result shows in console only will not write to a file

Tags: powershell

I have tried everything I can find online for posting my powershell script result to a text file with no luck. I only get results in the console and no text file is created.

See code below

```
$rootSitePath = "\\MyServer\JWS_SUL"

$paths = ($rootSitePath + "\" + "UNITED\Image\Ticket\Loadout"),
         ($rootSitePath + "\" + "UNITED\Image\Ticket\Pit2"),
         ($rootSitePath + "\" + "UNITED\Image\Ticket\Photo\Loadout")
         ($rootSitePath + "\" + "UNITED\Image\Ticket\Photo\Pit2")

$folder = $paths
foreach ($folder in $paths){
}
  if ($_.LastWriteTime.Date -ne (Get-Date).ToDay) {
     Write-Output $folder | Out-File -Path c:\temp\Test\BackupResults.txt
}
```

Console Output

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> C:\temp\JWS\TEST-1.ps1
\\MyServer\JWS_SUL\UNITED\Image\Ticket\Photo\Pit2

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

Your code updated with my network share

```
# --- Setup ---
$rootSitePath = "\\server\JWS_SUL"
$OutputPath   = "C:\temp\BackupResults.txt"
$CurDate = (Get-Date).ToShortDateString()  

#--- Cleanup from previous runs ---
If (Test-Path -Path "$OutputPath" ) {
  Remove-Item -Path "$OutputPath"
}

#--- Initialize paths - always use Join-Path ---
$paths = @((Join-Path -Path "$rootSitePath" -Childpath "\UNITED\Image\Ticket\Pit2"  )
           (Join-Path -Path "$rootSitePath" -Childpath "\UNITED\Image\Ticket\Loadout")
           (Join-Path -Path "$rootSitePath" -Childpath "\UNITED\Image\Ticket\Photo\Loadout"))


foreach ($folder in $paths){

  #--- Retrieve Folder time as ShortDate
  $FInfo = (Get-item -Path "$Folder").LastWriteTime.Date.ToShortDateString()
 
  if ($FInfo -ne $CurDate ) {
    Write-Output $folder | 
      Out-File -FilePath "C:\temp\BackupResults.txt" -Append
  }

} #End Foreach
```

Powershell console just shows this

```
PS Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\server\JWS_SUL> C:\temp\JWS\TEST-123.ps1
```

Comment: Your `foreach` loop has an empty body, and the `if` statement that should be inside that body is placed _after_ the loop. If you use `Out-File` without `-Append` in a loop, you'll overwrite the file in each iteration. `[datetime]` _instances_ have no `.Today` property, you must use `[datetime]::Today` (static property).

Comment: As shown, the code doesn't explain why you get any output at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a cleaned up version of your code with comments. It uses several of mkelements comments which I didn't see as I was writing and testing the code.

```
# --- Setup ---
$rootSitePath = "G:\BEKDocs"
$OutputPath   = "G:\Test\BackupResults.txt"
$CurDate = (Get-Date).ToShortDateString()  

#--- Cleanup from previous runs ---
If (Test-Path -Path "$OutputPath" ) {
  Remove-Item -Path "$OutputPath"
}

#--- Initialize paths - always use Join-Path ---
$paths = @((Join-Path -Path "$rootSitePath" -Childpath "Money"  )
           (Join-Path -Path "$rootSitePath" -Childpath "Outlook Files")
           (Join-Path -Path "$rootSitePath" -Childpath "Access"))


foreach ($folder in $paths){

  #--- Retrieve Folder time as ShortDate
  $FInfo = (Get-item -Path "$Folder").LastWriteTime.Date.ToShortDateString()
 
  if ($FInfo -ne $CurDate ) {
    Write-Output $folder | 
      Out-File -FilePath "G:\Test\BackupResults.txt" -Append
  }

} #End Foreach
```

Sample File Output:

```
G:\BEKDocs\Outlook Files
G:\BEKDocs\Access
```

The Money directory was changed today. Note the conversion to ShortDateString to eliminate the time element in the compare.

Comment: This seems to work great for folders on a Windows drive but when I change the paths to me network shared folders no file gets created?

Comment: I greatly appreciate your help. I have been trying to figure this out for 6 hours now. I'm not very good with powershell. Any ideas why the script won't work with my network share unc path? Thank you

Comment: timothytech I tried it against my NAS and it works fine. I did notice however that you have to be careful about what level you are  testing the folders at. I use RoboCopy to do daily backups of all my machines Data Drives (G:). On my NAS I have folders for each machine DellXPS8920, DellXPS8700, Dell137000, etc. However, the RoboCopy copies the Documents Folder under the relevant directory. The parent (machine) folder date does not change!

Comment: I don't what happen but this morning the script decided to work so thank you very much for your help much appreciated!